# How to view the size of the packets sent with IE8 developers tool?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I am used to use Firefox's FireBug and It is really good. I can see all the info I need.
Right now I am dealing with an application that is only compatible with IE, I am using the developer tools of IE but it is not as intuitive as Firebug and I can't figure out how to see the size of the packets sent from the client to the server, so far I see the time spent in each request.

So, is it possible to view the size of the packets sent with IE8 developers tool?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that can be done, but you could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) to analyze the traffic.